# In Go, why is my JSON decoding not working here?

Tags: json, go, decoding

I cannot get the standard library's `encoding/json` package to work for decoding JSON objects. Here's a minimal example:

```
b := []byte(`{"groups":[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]}`)
type Group struct{ name string }
var contents struct {
    groups []Group
}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &contents)
fmt.Printf("contents = %+v\nerr = %+v\n", contents, err)
```

This prints:

```
contents = {groups:[]}
err = nil
```

But I expect:

```
contents = {groups:[{name:foo} {name:bar}]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe show the contents of b?

Comment: Of course, in my application, the actual `Group` is more than a plain string. I left it as a struct in here for the sake of keeping the minimal example intact.

Comment: @JesseRusak: Sorry, I missed that in the initial copy-paste. Fixed now.

Comment: May I inquire why the question was down-voted? It's a valid question with a concise example. It *is* a duplicate, granted, but I don't see how I could have found that problem with more searching. It's always hard to search for something that you don't yet know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The field names have to start with a capital letter:

```
type Group struct{ Name string }
var contents struct {
    Groups []Group
}
```

Comment: Bah, I didn't see that because it is only mentioned in the documentation for `Marshal`, not in `Unmarshal`.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you!